# How can I shift my first element of an array using PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array store in this variable `$month_g`

```
dd($month_g);
```

I got

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 277664452
    "down_bytes" => 198868462
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 0
    "down_bytes" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => array:2 [▶]
  9 => array:2 [▶]
  10 => array:2 [▶]
  11 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I'm hoping to achieve

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 0
    "down_bytes" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 277664452
    "down_bytes" => 198868462
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => array:2 [▶]
  9 => array:2 [▶]
  10 => array:2 [▶]
  11 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I want to shift my 0 element to the second one. How do I do that in PHP ?

Comment: [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) and [`done()`](http://imgur.com/cXbcmim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$temp = $a[0];
$a[0] = $a[1];
$a[1] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one line solution like this:

```
$arr = array_combine(array(1, 0, 2), $arr);
```

Probably too fancy for that simple solution, but can be effective in larger swaps.